# Importing into Azure: SqlAzureV12DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

While trying to publish or preview Auto Schema Update to an Azure SQL Server V12 I'm getting the following error:

```
Web deployment task failed. (Could not generate deployment script.
Internal Error. The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlAzureV12DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database platform service.
Internal Error. The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlAzureV12DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database platform service.
  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD.)
```

I found a couple solutions for when this error is encountered when trying to import into a local SQL server, but I'm deploying **to** Azure SQL Database.

I downloaded and installed Microsoft SQL Server Data-Tier Application Framework (February 2015) (both the x64 and x86 versions as suggested at [Unable to import SQL Azure V12 BACPAC: "type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlAzureV12DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28566610/unable-to-import-sql-azure-v12-bacpac-type-microsoft-data-tools-schema-sql-sql) but the preview and deploy still fail.

I can connect to the database from my local machine using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (13.0.14000.36).

What is missing here?

---

Updates: 
I can successfully run Entity Framework's Migration's Update-Database from my local machine.
Publishing fails only when 'Update Database' is selected in the wizard (what I'm saying is that my publish setup is OK and works except the database bit).

Comment: Are you publishing to an Azure Web App?

Comment: Publishing as an Api App

Answer (score 0):

Try Web Deploy 3.6. [Download from here.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43717) There was a known issue in Web Deploy that does not correctly figure out the required component version. Web Deploy 3.6 or later should have fixed that issue.