# Count not load schema model from package. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, bacpac

[image]> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

> Internal Error. The database platform service with type
>   Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlAzureV12DatabaseSchemaProvider is
>   not valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must
>   provide the full type name of a valid database platform service.
>   (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)

I am getting above error when I am restoring Azure SQL Bacpac file in local environment. I have below environment on Azure and Local.

> **Azure SQL RTM Version** : Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Aug
>   29 2017 13:06:11   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
>
> **Local Environment SQL RTM Version** : Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) -
>   14.0.1000.169 (X64)   Aug 22 2017 17:04:49    Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation    Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro
>   10.0  (Build 15063: )

Can anyone please suggest the compatible version of Management studio or SQL RTM for above Azure SQL RTM database restore ?

Comment: have you resolved this issue?

Comment: Yes, It is resolved after upgrading my sql server version.

Answer (score 7):

I haven't managed to solve it through SSMS, the only way that worked was through CMD: 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe" /a:Import /sf:PATH-TO-BACPAC-FILE /tsn:SERVER-NAME /tdn:DATABASE-NAME /tu:USER-NAME /tp:PASSWORD

- Replace the upper-cases with your SERVER/DB info.
- Use correct folder (110,120,130,140...)

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me. USER-NAME has to be the owner of the master db.

Answer (score 3):

Please download the latest version of SSMS from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms), it may solve the issue.

It seems a known issue the error you are receiving. On [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2015/04/08/bacpac-could-not-load-schema-model-from-package/) Microsoft blog post, they were successful restoring to a SQL Server 2012 instance using SSMS 2014.

You will find more workarounds and solutions on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28566610/unable-to-import-sql-azure-v12-bacpac-type-microsoft-data-tools-schema-sql-sql) StackOverflow thread.

Comment: I tried the same way that you suggested but now getting another error. Please see this error message.
Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 33161, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Database master keys without password are not supported in this version of SQL Server.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
CREATE MASTER KEY;

Comment: It is a known issue. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2017/03/30/exported-database-from-azure-sql-failed-to-be-imported-to-azure-sql-or-to-local-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

1st we need to check, In version of .bacpac is creted. the higher version will support lower version of .bacpac, but lower version will not support will higher version of .bacpac.