# BACPAC from SQL Azure Error when import it

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, bacpac

I tried to import my db from SQL Azure, but I am getting the next error in SQL Server Management Studio  from each version that I specified:

### SQL Server Management Studio v17.9.1:

Could not load schema model from package. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Internal Error. The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql150DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. 
You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database platform service. 
(Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)

### SQL Server Management Studio v18.0 Preview 5:

Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first. (System.Data)

The version when I am trying to import SQL Server is

Comment: What is the version of SQL Server? What is the expected size of the database?

Comment: The source is "Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8" and the destination is in my VM is "Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4293803) - 14.0.2002.14 (X64)",  the size of db is 4.8Gb approximately.

Comment: Try using SqlPSqlPackage.exe /Action:Import /SourceFile:"C:\test.bacpac" /TargetConnectionString:"Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=TestDB; User Id=Testuser;Password='test'"ackage instead of SSMS:

Comment: So you are pulling a bacpac out of SQl Azure (SQL PaaS) and trying to import it onto SQL Server inside a VM? Please edit the question and clarify

Answer (score 4):

Uninstall SQL Server Management Studio 2018, then install SSMS v17.9.1. Re-import the Bacpac and you will have better results.

Comment: I was using SSMS 18.0 Preview 5 and then 6 and ran into this issue. Backing down to v17.9.1 resolved the issue I was also seeing the open DataReader error.

Answer (score 0):

For this import error, you can try this way :

Install [Microsoft SQL Server Data-Tier Application Framework (February 2015)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45886) ( Both the x64 and x86 versions).

Here is the link may be useful for you:
[Unable to import SQL Azure V12 BACPAC: "type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlAzureV12DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28566610/unable-to-import-sql-azure-v12-bacpac-type-microsoft-data-tools-schema-sql-sql)

Answer (score 0):

I've actually been having a very similar problem.
Although I had a slightly different error message for MSSMSv17 (in regards to the additional information).
But the same error for MSSMSv18 (Preview 6).

So after trying many different things until I had irreversible damaged my SQL server installations to the point where I had to reinstall Windows, the first thing I installed was SQL Server 2017 & MSSMSv18. Which produced the same error as before. But MSSMSv17 worked, soo... yay?